# Rails path shows up a .id not /id when updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a routing issue. When I click submit on the edit form for an event, I am rerouted to a page with .id instead of /id, which clearly does not exist and produces an error. Any insight would be greatly appreciated

```
error: No route matches [PATCH] "/event.2"
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
     
     root 'welcome#welcome'
     get '/user/:id/' => 'users#main'
     get '/event' => 'events#index'
     get '/event/new/' => 'events#new'
     get '/event/:id/' => 'events#main'
     post 'event' => 'events#create'
     delete '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
     post '/submit' => 'welcome#submit'
    
    
     resources :events do
         member do
             get :coming, :going
             post :destroy, :update
        end
    end
     
     resources :users do
         member do
             get :following, :followers
         end
     end
     resources :friends,       only: [:create, :destroy]
     resources :comings,       only: [:create, :destroy]
     resources :relationships,  only: [:create, :destroy]
     
     get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
     get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
    
        enter code here
    
    end

#events controller methods#
def edit
     @event = Event.find(params[:id])

end


    def update
     @event = Event.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
         if @event.update(event_params)
             format.html { redirect_to @event }
             else
             format.html { render :edit }
         end
     end
    end
    
#edit view#
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="edit-event">
  <div class="container">
    
    <h2>Tell us about your dog!</h2>
    <div class="edit-area">
        <%= form_for(@event) do |u| %>
        <div class="field">
            Event Name:
            <%= u.text_field :event_name %>
            Event Place:
            <%= u.text_field :place %>
            <%= u.submit "Submit"%>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
   
</div>
```

## updated Routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 
 root 'welcome#welcome'
 get '/user/:id/' => 'users#main'
 get '/event' => 'events#index'
 get '/event/new/' => 'events#new'
 get '/event/:id/' => 'events#main'
 post 'event' => 'events#create'
 delete '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
 post '/submit' => 'welcome#submit'


resources :events, only: [:edit, :update]
 
 resources :users do
     member do
         get :following, :followers
     end
 end
 resources :friends,       only: [:create, :destroy]
 resources :comings,       only: [:create, :destroy]
 resources :relationships,  only: [:create, :destroy]
 
 get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
 get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

Comment: Why do you have those extra routes for events (outside the resources block) ? What is the path that you are redirected to

Comment: @FrederickCheung I'm not sure what you mean.I updated my routes form but am receiving the same error. What modifications do u suggest?

Comment: @BNYCS92 what came out of the story?
It would be helpful if you can post your solution(whatever you remember now)

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case it doesn't know exactly what route to use when you do a `redirect_to`. I would recommend change `resources :events` to `resources :events, only: [:edit, :update]` and deleting the manual paths you created for the similar routes. The other option is to name the manual routes and use that in your redirects and link_tos.
`get 'event/:id', to: 'events#edit', as: :edit_event`

Comment: I made the changes above but unfortunately i'm receiving same error. Any ideas why?

Comment: I've seen when you generate paths manually starting with a slash and containing a named param it changes it to a . Instead of using a slash for the path

Comment: @BNYCS92 I updated my answer, please remove the manual paths that the resources call will generate

Comment: thanks for the help. For some odd reason I am still receiving the same error. I am adding my updated routes file. Let me know if you know what's wrong with it please.